# TypeError: Cannot read property 'simpleResponse' of undefined

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am developing an open-ended question answer chatbot in dialogflow. While entering the response sometimes it accepts the response and sometimes it throws this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'simpleResponse' of undefined at DialogflowConversation.response

Here is my code:

```
app.intent('First', (conv) => {
    const ans = conv.parameters.any;
    if(type[0] === 'RATING'){
        if(ans == 1){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else if(ans == 2){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else if(ans == 3){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else if(ans == 4){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else if(ans == 5){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else if(ans === 'can you help me' || ans === 'help' || ans === 'help me'){
            checkhelp_logout = "help";
            flag_log_help = 2;
            conv.ask('Would you like some help?');
        }
        else if(ans === 'logout'){
            checkhelp_logout = "logout";
            flag_log_help = 2;
            conv.ask('Did you say logout?');
        }
        else if(ans === 'sign out'){
            checkhelp_logout = "logout";
            flag_log_help = 2;
            conv.ask('Did you say sign out?');
        }
        else{
            conv.add('Please enter a valid number');
            conv.ask(qstion[0]);
        }
    }
    else{
         if(ans === 'can you help me' || ans === 'help' || ans === 'help me'){
            checkhelp_logout = "help";
            flag_log_help = 2;
            conv.ask('Would you like some help?');
        }
        else if(ans === 'logout'){
            checkhelp_logout = "logout";
            flag_log_help = 2;
            conv.ask('Did you say logout?');
        }
        else if(ans === 'sign out'){
            checkhelp_logout = "logout";
            flag_log_help = 2;
            conv.ask('Did you say sign out?');
        }
        else{
            //conv.add(ans);
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
    }
});
```

The type array stores the type of question , i.e., if it is a rating question or a descriptive question. The qstion array stores the question which are coming from the API.
Can you help me why it's working sometimes and not sometimes not.

Comment: Under what conditions do you get that error? Do you know what "branch" of the code you are in when you get that error?

Comment: When you get that error, can you provide the full details including the several lines of code points? Having a full stacktrace can help identify where this issue may be happening. My initial guess is that `qstion[1]` is undefined sometimes.

Comment: @KLP it basically arises in the rating part, where I am comparing the answer to 1 to 5.

Comment: @NickFelker qstion[1] is working fine, no issues on that, it has issue with the response coming from the user. For eg. if I enter 4 then it shows this error, and when I enter 4 again in the next testing it works absolutely fine

Comment: Can you verify that you're getting the right parameter in your code?

Comment: @NickFelker yes, I am using sys.any as my parameter and in the code I have used parameters.any

Comment: But if you look at the request body do you always see the right parameters?

Comment: How do you check that?

Comment: I checked in the queryResult.queryText, the response is the same which I entered